# Basic Java program tune up assistance

Tags: java

My program asks the user for their name, then asks for a number of shuffles of 3 random numbers.

When one of the shuffles adds to the desired number (which is 31) the shuffle stops. I need to happen that the program only reads the LAST SHUFFLE. E.g.

> how many shuffles do you want: 3
>
> 10 + 11 + 10 = 31 congrats you are the winner!!

The current output is:

> 9 + 6 + 8
>
> 8 + 10 + 12
>
> 7 + 9 + 11

I need assistance in making sure the user cannot put non alphabetical characters in their name. I also need the ability to be able to print out how many shuffles the user had before the numbers were printed out.

Here is my code,

```
  `import java.util.InputMismatchException;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Random;

 public class StringVariables {



public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {

    // user inputs their name in this section
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
 //enter their first name
    String first_name;
    System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
    first_name = user_input.next();
  //enter their last name
    String last_name;
    System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
    last_name = user_input.next();
 //full name printed together
    String full_name;
    full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;

    System.out.println(full_name + " Is Now Playing");

    // this is the shuffle portion as well as something to see if a number

    int numShuffles = -1;
    while (numShuffles < 0) {

        System.out.println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled? ");

        try {
            numShuffles = user_input.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException inputException) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid number. \n");
            //this is the buffer that resets if the user types a letter instead of a number, or any other character
            user_input.next();
        }
    } 

    // here is going to be the loop for shuffles

    // we are now going to generate their random number and add a delay
    // after completing their name fields

    delay(3000);
    System.out
            .println(" You will be given a hand of 3 random numbers between 7-13"
                    + "\n you will be drawn a the number of shuffles as you entered above ");

    delay(2000);
    System.out
            .println(" Then, the computer will add the random numbers and  if it is equal to 31, you win.");

    /*
     * end of explanation of the game, next i will create a new screen with
     * the user's name and numbers
     */

    delay(4000);
    // printing 25 blank lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        System.out.println(" ");


    System.out.println("User playing: " + full_name);

    System.out.println("Your lucky numbers are...");

    // random number generator

    Random random = new Random();



    while (true) {

        // the shuffle loop
        boolean isWinner = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numShuffles; i++) {
            int num1 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
            int num2 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
            int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);

            System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " = "
                    + (num1 + num2 + num3));

  // adding the numbers together          

            if (num1 + num2 + num3 == 31) {
                isWinner = true;
                System.out
                        .println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
                break;
                //if you loose every shuffle
            }
        }
        if (!isWinner)
            System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");

        // play again prompt
        System.out
                .println(" Do you want to play again? (If you do enter y or yes) \n To exit press any other key ");
        String input = user_input.next();
        if (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(input) &&  !"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // if pressed y or yes the program will run again with the same number of shuffles entered from before
    user_input.close();
}

// delay field

public static void delay(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException exp) {

        // delay field

    }
}
 }`
```

Comment: It's not a shuffle as you can have duplicate numbers. e.g. 7, 7 and 7.

Comment: duplicate numbers are okay for this project @PeterLawrey

Comment: is there anything you can do to help?

Answer (score 1):

```
Arraylist numberStore = new Arraylist();
for (int i = 0; i < numShuffles; i++) {
    int num1 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
    int num2 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
    int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);

    System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " = " + (num1 + num2 + num3));

    numberStore.add(num1 + num2 + num3);

}

int lastNumber = (numberStore.size() - 1);
if (lastNumber == 31) {
        isWinner = true;
        System.out
                .println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
        break;
        //if you loose every shuffle
}
```

> to make sure that only the last shuffle can get read as a winner or loser.

Because you are initializing your num1, num 2... variables inside of your for loop then those variables are scoped to that for loop. I would suggest that if you want to make sure that only one set of numbers can be judged then you move the scope out of the loop. Adding the totals to an array would then allow you to choose as many as you want to judge.

When it comes to sterilizing your inputs you can use [`util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to do most of it for you with a little knowledge of regex:

```
while (!scan.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
    System.out.println("Nope, that's not it!");
    sc.next();
}
```

This will stop your scanner allowing any none alphabetical char's being entered, you can read more about Regex with [this tool](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: thank you! i tested the code but it still stops the shuffle loop if the answer is correct before the loop finishes. any more suggestions

Comment: do you think you could help me implement that into the code. i am having a brain fart day and just cannot think for the life of me

Comment: What that loop is doing is generating three numbers and then checking if they are = to 31.

What you need to do is to generate the numbers, save them outside of your loop, and then check the final three. If you give me 40 minutes to get home from work then I will help you implement that if you haven't worked it out by then.

Comment: what happens with this code is that it doesnt repeat to ask the "enter your first name" prompt again, it just continues the rest of the code prompting to fill in the last name @MaxCheetham

Comment: I have updated my answer with some java-pseudo code to get only the last number to be checked (although I haven't tested it for errors)

Comment: there is a couple errors, if you could run it through i have no idea how to fix it im sorry im no help to this situation

Comment: numberStore is not added as a variable and i cant figure out how to do that. since numberstore isnt added into my program yet.

Comment: Sorry man, long day at work, numberStore is an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). I have updated the answer.

Comment: awesome! its working perfect subside one  issue. when the last number is actually 31 it doesn't play the congratulations, you won loop. im trying to figure it out myself but cant get my head around it

Comment: regardless of what i do it only prints out the loser prompt even if it wins